# How to choose the database at run time based on the product selection in Spring boot and MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

In my case, I have three different products (Eg: Product 1, Product 2, Product 3), each product has a different databases (Eg: Productdb1, Productdb2 and Productdb3) and different domain (Eg: product1.com, product2.com and product3.com) but the Appengine (API) is same. The domain and Appengine will communicate through the REST.

**Scenario :** 
If the user entered in product1.com, the Appengine will access Productdb1 database. If the user entered in product2.com, Appengine will access Productdb2 database.

> Depending on the product the API should access its related database.

**Technology :**
Spring Boot, Spring Security, Spring data and MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Your application basically needs to connect to multiple databases. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Comment: Yes you are right @Sharadha. But baeldung(first link) used Hibernate for mysql database. And then am not looking for different datasources like Mysql, Oracle and Mongodb connect at same time. I want to be multiple database with the single datasource.